# Basic Javascript and JSON object

Tags: javascript

```
function load() {
// JavaScript
var myObject = new Object();
myObject.name = "Cessna";
myObject.model = "152";
myObject.year = "1984";
myObject.color1 = "white";
myObject.color2 = "blue";

// JSON
var myObject_JSON = {"name":"Cessna", "model":"152", "year":"1984", "color1":"white", "color2":"blue"};

var strJava = "JavaScript Object\n";
    strJava += "Name    = " + myOjbect.name   + "\n";
    strJava += "Model   = " + myOjbect.model  + "\n";
    strJava += "Year    = " + myOjbect.year   + "\n";
    strJava += "Color 1 = " + myOjbect.color1 + "\n";
    strJava += "Color 2 = " + myOjbect.color2;

var strJSON = "JSON Object\n";
    strJSON += "Name    = " + myObject_JSON["name"]   + "\n";
    strJSON += "Model   = " + myObject_JSON["model"]  + "\n";
    strJSON += "Year    = " + myObject_JSON["year"]   + "\n";
    strJSON += "Color 1 = " + myObject_JSON["color1"] + "\n";
    strJSON += "Color 2 = " + myObject_JSON["color2"];

window.alert(strJava);
window.alert(strJSON);  
}
```

So my task is converting the JavaScript object into JSON object.
And I want to check whether my conversion is correct or not. Thus, I am trying to display the value of each.
But I couldn't get the window.alert() function work. It does not display anything while the page loads.

P/S: there is one HTML file, when `<body onload="load();">`

Any advice why the alert function not working successfully?

Comment: Have you tried alert(strJava) instead of window.alert(strJava)?

Comment: And have you checked the console as well?

Comment: What you call JSON here is not JSON, but a JavaScript object literal. JSON is a specific format a string can have that encodes data with syntax similar to JavaScript object literal. To make a JSON out of your `myObject`, `JSON.stringify(myObject)` suffices.

Comment: I think you're deeply confused about the difference between JSON and JavaScript object literals. Anyway, after fixing the typo, does your code now work?

Comment: Take a look at the console, if you know what that is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you defined myObject variable but used myOjbect.

Answer (score 0):

you defined `myObject` variable but used `myOjbect`.

In the below code snippet, I just correct `myOjbect` to `myObject`.

```js
window.onload = load();
function load() {
  // JavaScript
  var myObject = new Object();
  myObject.name = "Cessna";
  myObject.model = "152";
  myObject.year = "1984";
  myObject.color1 = "white";
  myObject.color2 = "blue";

  // JSON
  var myObject_JSON = {
    "name": "Cessna",
    "model": "152",
    "year": "1984",
    "color1": "white",
    "color2": "blue"
  };

  var strJava = "JavaScript Object\n";
  strJava += "Name    = " + myObject.name + "\n";
  strJava += "Model   = " + myObject.model + "\n";
  strJava += "Year    = " + myObject.year + "\n";
  strJava += "Color 1 = " + myObject.color1 + "\n";
  strJava += "Color 2 = " + myObject.color2;

  var strJSON = "JSON Object\n";
  strJSON += "Name    = " + myObject_JSON["name"] + "\n";
  strJSON += "Model   = " + myObject_JSON["model"] + "\n";
  strJSON += "Year    = " + myObject_JSON["year"] + "\n";
  strJSON += "Color 1 = " + myObject_JSON["color1"] + "\n";
  strJSON += "Color 2 = " + myObject_JSON["color2"];

  window.alert(strJava);
  window.alert(strJSON);
}
```

```html
<div>
</div>
```